# CosmosDb SDK v3 - Create container with ttl on

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a `.NET Core 3` web api that connects to the `CosmosDb`. I have a "Initializer" that on service startup check if the database and container exists, if not, it creates them. But after that, I need to go manually to the settings and turn on the ttl to `On (no default)` like following:

[image: Scale & Settings]

Startup:

```cs
private void InitializeCosmosClientInstance(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbManager>(CosmosDbInitializer.InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(this.azureConfiguration.CosmosDb).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
}
```

InitializeCosmosClientInstance:

```cs
public static async Task<CosmosDbManager> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(CosmosDbConfiguration cosmosDbConfiguration)
{
    SmartGuard.NotNull(() => cosmosDbConfiguration, cosmosDbConfiguration);

    // Build cosmos client builder

    CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(cosmosDbConfiguration.Account, cosmosDbConfiguration.Key);

    // Build cosmos client

    CosmosClient client = clientBuilder
                        .WithConnectionModeDirect()
                        .WithSerializerOptions(new CosmosSerializationOptions()
                        {
                            PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                        })
                        .Build();

    // Get container

    Container container = client.GetContainer(cosmosDbConfiguration.Database, cosmosDbConfiguration.Container);

    // Initialize service

    CosmosDbManager cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbManager(container, client);

    // Create database if not exist

    DatabaseResponse database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(cosmosDbConfiguration.Database).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // After database created, create container

    await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(cosmosDbConfiguration.Container, cosmosDbConfiguration.PartitionKey).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Return the instance

    return cosmosDbService;
}
```

How can I do this with the SDK and not need to turn this on manually?
Thank you.

Comment: is this it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.containerproperties.defaulttimetolive?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I believe that this is what I was looking for... I will check this and try it.

Comment: @4c74356b41 that was the option. Thank you for your response. Maybe you can add it as answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to configure TTL you would use `DefaultTimeToLive` property under ContainerProperties.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.containerproperties.defaulttimetolive?view=azure-dotnet